# custom post type archive page url to point to Page permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I wish that my 'custom post type archive page' would point to Page.

The situations is as follows:

I have `Page` in Wordpress with permalink `http://myurl.com/galleries`. This page shows list of posts with custom post type = `vmgallery`. I have custom logic for this page that is working fine.

From another view, this page works like "custom post type archive page", because it displays all posts for given custom post type vmgallery. Currently, if user goes to http://myurl.com/vmgallery/ wordpress is loading archive page (archive.php), instead, I wish `http://myurl.com/galleries` page is loaded.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have multiple options here.

**1. Define post type archive slug on post type registration**

By setting `'has_archive' => 'galleries'` you can define custom post type archive slug.
Check [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#has_archive).
Then you can delete your page "galleries" then add & customize the `archive-post_type.php`

**2. Disable default archive for post type**

Disable the archive by setting `'has_archive' => false` then keep the page for the post type archive.

**3. Redirect archive requests to your page**

You can permanent redirect default archive request to your page.

```
function archive_to_custom_archive() {
    if( is_post_type_archive( 'post_slug' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/galleries/' ), 301 );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'archive_to_custom_archive' );
```

> I will say the first method is good!

Comment: Can you please suggest wich option would be better if I also have "custom taxonomy for this custom post type" (custom taxonomy name is 'gallery_categories', example of galery category is "auto"). And I wish http://myurl.com/galleries/auto would work the same as http://myurl.com/galleries. I wish it would have almost the same code (code would check if it is 'galleries' or 'galleries'/xxx and act in very the same way with minor differences)?

Comment: Custom post type archive and custom taxonomy archive  are different. The fist option is always good but it will not work as  http://myurl.com/galleries/auto
You can not pull results from term `auto`. For this you will need custom page template and URL rewrite to parse the request as http://example.com/page-name/?mytax=auto

Comment: What if you want to translate "galleries" :))

Comment: Great. For me only worked the third option beacuse my case was about redirect the archive request to a certain post of this post type. So I added home_url( '/galleries/some-post-slug' ) inside the wp_redirect() method and so it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is below code to remove archive page link with not affecting in single post url.and you can create page with archive slug.

```
function dg_custom_post_type_args( $args, $post_type ) {
if ( $post_type === "custom post type" ) {
    $args['rewrite'] = array(
    'with_front' => false,
    'slug' => 'slug here'
  );
}

return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'dg_custom_post_type_args', 20, 2 );
```